# How to use the Run within the TextBlock without space in XAML Winrt?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run  Text="{Binding Percentage}"/>
    <Run Text="%"/>
</TextBlock>
```

I know this seems like a trivial question but I was wondering in the above code if **Percentage** value was 95 then it displays **95 %** and not **95%**. That is there is a space between the Run which I don't want. How to remove this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try writing them in the same line. e.g.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run  Text="{Binding Percentage}"/><Run Text="%"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Yeah that worked.Thanks a lot. Any explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Text between `Runs` also gets rendered so it treats new line as a space.

Comment: Oh didn't know that. Thanks again for the info!